# Group by two columns and do a ToDictionary with a Tuple as Key C# Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ormlite-servicestack

I have a piece of code where I want to group by two fields and do a ToDictionary on it with the two field as a tuple key. I am not sure of the syntax. Following is what I have, But the problem is it creates a Tuple with single item.

```
var count = this.Db.Query<EmployeeCount>(@"select
            employername, ein, month, headcount
            from employerInfo A inner join MonthlyInfo B on (A.Id = B.Id)
            where A.ClientId = @Client",
            new { run.Client })
            .GroupBy(r => new { r.EIN, r.EmployerName})
            .ToDictionary(pair => Tuple.Create<string>(pair.Key.ToString()), pair => pair.ToDictionary(r => (Months)r.month, r => r.headcount));
```

And my EmployeeCount class is

```
 private class CountQuery
    {
        public string EmployerName;
        public string EIN;
        public int Month;
        public int HeadCount;
    }
```

I try to do a Tuple.Create, but i am not sure how to notify that the params would be EIN and Employername for the Tuple.

Comment: FYI you should use POCO's with public **properties**, i.e. instead of **fields** with OrmLite.

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out myself as below

```
var count = this.Db.Query<EmployeeCount>(@"select
        employername, ein, month, headcount
        from employerInfo A inner join MonthlyInfo B on (A.Id = B.Id)
        where A.ClientId = @Client",
        new { run.Client })
        .GroupBy(r => new { r.EIN, r.EmployerName}).ToDictionary(pair => Tuple.Create<string,string>(pair.Key.EIN.ToString(),pair.Key.EmployerName), pair => pair.ToDictionary(r => (Months)r.ReportingMonth, r => r.FTECount))
```